# Show multiple details in console, but not in textarea. How to show specific lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, java, python, android, c

class search extends JFrame{

```
private Container container;
private Font font,font2;
private JLabel label;
private JTextField textField;
private JButton search;
private JTextArea textarea;

search(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100,40,600,380);
    this.setTitle("SEARCH");

    container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(null);

    font = new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,14);
    font2 = new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,18);

    label = new JLabel("SEARCH : ");
    label.setBounds(40,20,150,50);
    label.setFont(font);
    container.add(label);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(140,25,200,40);
    textField.setFont(font2);
    container.add(textField);

    search = new JButton("SEARCH");
    search.setBounds(370,25,110,37);
    search.setFont(font);
    container.add(search);

    textarea = new JTextArea();
    textarea.setBounds(40,85,500,200);
    textarea.setFont(font2);
    container.add(textarea);

    search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String x = textField.getText();
            try{
                File file = new File("allinfo.txt");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String s = reader.readLine();
                while(s!=null){
                    String string[] = s.split(" ");
                    String a = string[0];
                    String b = string[1];
                    String c = string[2];
                    String d = string[3];

                    String f = a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d;

                    if (x.equals(a)){
                        System.out.println(f);
                        textarea.setText(f);
                    }
                    s = reader.readLine();
                }
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    search frame = new search();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

It is a search option where I can search for a person's name. If there are two people who have the same name, both the option should show in the text area, but the text area show only one person details. But the console is printing all personal details. I need help with how I can show all the details in textarea.

Comment: Is this java or js?

Comment: this is javaswing

Comment: Then remove the extra tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
textarea.setText(f);
```

use

```
textarea.append(f + "\n");
```

Comment: ok it works but not like console. console prints a person details then another line shows other person details. but textarea didn't take any new line

Comment: @SafinDipro check the edit, you need to ad a newline character